# How do I clone someone else's GitHub repo as a subdirectory of my repo?

Tags: github, subdirectory, git-clone

I would like to add functions from another repo into my repo.  To preserve the edit history and licensing info from that repo in the cleanest way, while still building on and modifying that repo to fit into mine, I want to clone it as a subdirectory in my repo.

This has been asked [here](https://gist.github.com/Restuta/434ba33ce2267be9adf2) but I don't see a clean answer in that link.  Is there a clean and simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the feature called `GitHub submodules` which you find a detail description [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

TL;DR

`git submodule add <git@github ...> folder/to/submodule/`